# How deep does a pool of honey have to be to regenerate life?

Tags: terraria

I want to make a pool of honey in prep for boss battles, but I also don't want to have the honey make me move extremely slow either. Is it possible to make the honey shallow enough to provide regen, while not slowing me down?

Comment: As far as my knowledge about honey goes, you must be underwater (underhoney?). So 3 blocks deep. I'm not sure about this though, since I never work with honey.

Comment: @VascovdEng totally incorrect. 1 block deep is enough, not sure how much lower it might go though.

Comment: @VascovdEng I think you where looking for the word submerged. As in "completely submerged in the honey"

Comment: @MennoGouw Hehe, yeah I forgot the correct word for the context. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A player entering Honey will be granted a life regeneration Buff that will last for as long as they remain submerged, plus 30 seconds after leaving it.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Honey

From recent experience, I can tell you that any amount of your body being in honey is enough for the buff to work, with the 'cooldown' starting immediately after your entire body is out of the honey.

Comment: How far submerged though? 1/2 block? 1 block? Over their head, or just up to it?

Comment: No problem.  I didn't know you were going to confirm it yourself later when I put that edit in.  So I figured I'd try to offer a definite answer.  Glad I could help.

Comment: The 30 seconds after part helps. So I could jump into a shallow pool of honey then up onto platforms where i can move more freely, cool.

Comment: It's recommended you do so too, since Honey seems to inhibit your movement more than water or lava does.

Comment: I have yet to get started on this. Any way honey can be shallow enough to not slow you, same as lava can be shallow enough to not destroy items?